# connectionStrings configSource in App.config not working

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, connection-string

I'm trying to separate my connection string from my `App.config`, and as you can't do transformations like with `Web.config`, I thought may I could use the `configSource` attribute to point to another config file with the connection string in, but it doesn't seem to be working.

This works, `App.config`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=*snip*" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
      connectionString="Server=*snip*" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

But this doesn't, `App.config`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=*snip*" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings configSource="connections.config" />      
</configuration>
```

`connections.config`:

```xml
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
      connectionString="*snip*" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I'm looking for the simplest of solutions.

Any ideas?

Comment: _What_ is not working? What are the symptoms? What you posted works for me. Are the `.config` files in the same directory?

Comment: The class I am using uses a `DbContext` which takes a connection string parameter, so I pass to that DefaultConnection. It works when the connectionString is defined in the App.config but not in the separate file.

Comment: Make sure both files are saved and in the same directory (or that the relative path is correct in `configSource`).

Comment: They're sitting next to each other in the same directory. It's bizarre.

Comment: I've put the code into a test console app and I am getting `{"The type initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig' threw an exception."}` and `{"Unable to open configSource file 'connections.config'. (*project directory*\\bin\\Debug\\TestApp.vshost.exe.config line 17)"}` which makes me wonder if it isn't copying the other config file to the build directory...

Answer (score 136, accepted):

If you added the file yourself, the build action (in the file properties) may not have been set correctly.

The `Copy to Output Directory` option needs to be `Copy if newer` or `Copy Always` to ensure that the `.config` file ends up in the `bin` directory, otherwise it will not be there and trying to load the configuration will fail.

**Right Click** on file and then Click **properties**

[image]

Change to **"Copy always"** or **"Copy if newer"**

[image]

Comment: Note: Thus, in some web apps, you will have too add reference to: configSource="bin\connections.config" instead of configSource="connections.config"

Comment: I was facing the same issue and before finding this post, I suspected this to be an output copying problem. So I went ahead and first checked out `app.config` properties, which apparently are set to **None** and **Do not copy**. Why does this setting not work for `ConnectionStrings.config`?

Comment: @dotNET App.config has an special treatment during build event. It's transformed (if any transform is defined), renamed to match exe name's and copied to output folder as part of msbuild task

Comment: I also had to set my connections.config "Build Action" to Content... then it actually copied it to the root (where I was expecting it).

Comment: I had same issue, I was using custom configuration section. Problem was path which I specified was relative to app.config file, but in order for it to work path should be relative to <dllname>.dll.config location. It fixed the issue. It was unable to find that file in previous location.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and Oded solution works for me. But I will just precise that to find out how to change the file "Copy to Output Directory option" to be "copy if newer or copy always", you have to

- rigth click on the file
- select properties
- go to advance
- then will see copy to output directory and choise copy if newer or copy always

This helped me, I hope it will help you too

Comment: Go to advance, if you are using Categorized Properties Panel.