# Retrieve connection string from text file and update in app.config

Tags: vb.net, winforms, app-config

I am just get in VB this two month and not really familiar with it. Hopefully can get advise here.

I am working on **app.config** and unable to figure out the way to update the app.config by retrieve the connection string from text file outside. When execute the program, the app.config should automatically retrieve the connection string from text file without required user to click on any button.

I have tried the way but it is not worked, app.config is not updated successfully:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="VMMPNP3.My.MySettings.VMMPNP3ConnectionString" connectionString=".\\connection.txt"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Connection string in the text file:

```
Data Source=ECSTSRD;Initial Catalog=VMMQT1;User ID=pnpuser;Password=pnpuser123
```

I have search through internet but I cannot found any article which similar with my situation.

Anyone do know what is the problem, please help and advise.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you get any error upon trying?

Comment: @E-rGabrielDoronila Nope, only the data retrieved is not from the database that I specified in connection string. I use break point to debug the program, found out the connection string in the text file can be read, but the data is still wrong. After first login is failed, I try to login again,  it is successful and data retrieved is correct

Answer (score 1):

I could be wrong, but I don't believe referencing external files like that is supported.

If you want to keep your connection strings in a file separate to your app.config, you can do it using the `configSource` attribute, as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494(v=vs.110).aspx) and [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14873126/connectionstrings-configsource-in-app-config-not-working).

Comment: By using configSource, means I have to open the program and modify the connection string if I wanted to change the database?

Actually, my text file is placed in my debug folder, and i was thinking to change the connection string in the text file without open the program to change

Comment: What do you mean by 'open the program'? Config files are text files you can edit while the application is running and IIS will pick up the new values. In what circumstances will you be looking to change the connection string while the application is running?

Comment: sorry, the text file I means is the text document that created outside. To change the connection string, I only need to do in text document, because now I have 4 database which shared 1 program. I was thinking to change the string outside rather than change the connection string in app.config manually.

you get me?

Comment: Ok, so you want to programmatically change the connection string in the text file? I'm not sure I can help without probably quite a lot more information about the application...