# Connection String in separate config file with EF model designer

Tags: c#, entity-framework

How do i get the EF model designer at design time see the connection string in a separate config file without prompting for 'Choose you data connection' when i try and update model from database.

I have a separate config file for connection strings to run against different environments. In app.config i use `<connectionStrings configSource="connections.config">`.

I do not want to save the connection in app.config or web.config. Run time works fine just seems to be a big limitation on the designer.

To reproduce the problem simply create an new ADO.net Entity Data Model. Store the connection string in the app.config. you will get an app fonfig like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <configuration>
   <configSections>
     <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
     <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
   </configSections>
   <startup>
     <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
   </startup>
   <entityFramework>
     <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
     <providers>
       <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
     </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=myserver;initial catalog=Devdb;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
 </configuration>
```

Now copy the connectionstring and put it in a new file 'myconnections.config'

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=myserver;initial catalog=Devdb;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Edit the app.config and change the connection string settings to

```
<connectionStrings configSource="myconnections.config">
```

The model designer will now not know about the connection. If you click 'Update Model from Database' it will prompt you for the connection and want to save a connection back to the app.config. Really frustrating.

Comment: you can modify the connection string in the app.config/or web.config. even you dont want to save the connection in `app.config or web.config`, you need to put your connectionString in your application.

Comment: Connection strings work fine in separate config file, I can edit them there. Run time works a treat. However the designer struggles, if i right click 'Update model from DB' i get the 'Choose your data connection' this doesnt happen if the connection is in app.config or web.config

Comment: it means that your connectionString at config file is not properly configured to connect to your database.

Comment: It is a copy and paste of what is created in the app.config. To reproduce what i mean just create a model.edmx, save the connection string in app.config. edit the app.config and set the connnectionstrings to 'configSource="myconnections.config" this will use an external file. in myconnections.config paste in the connection string

Comment: i guess this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14873126/connectionstrings-configsource-in-app-config-not-working) is related in your problem.

Comment: Yep kind of, in my scenario everything is working at run time, I just cant get the designer to work well with moving the connection strings.

Comment: have you overcame this issue ? I can't push designer to work with external config file with my connection strings. I found small discussion on it [here](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/discussions/528758) and it seems the designer can't do this.

Comment: Unfortunately there was now way to overcome this problem and I abandoned the idea of having a separate config file. With the forthcoming EF7 not supporting EDMX (afaik) I began to question putting any more time into this.

Comment: Still no solution to this? Having the same issues

Comment: Sorry, never found a way around this, gave up in the end as model designer is being dumped in the next release of EF so not worth the investment.

Answer (score 0):

Well I know this question is 5 years old, but I actually found the solution. I am using VS2019 and when I add a new data connection in Server Explorer, EF will see my new connection. While this is not actually the perfect solution because we have to add connection string separately, it still works.