# Creating an external file for connection strings in WPF project

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, connection-string

I have the following steps for an ASP.Net project : 
1- Created a connectionStrings.config file (web configuration file)
2- Removed

> < connectionStrings >

part from Web.config file and pasted to connectionStrings.config file
3- I wrote the following line on Web.config file.

```
<connectionStrings configSource="connectionStrings.config"/>
```

This worked perfectly on ASP.Net project.
I did the same thing on a WPF project, except I added Application Configuration File.
But I get this exception:

> {"The type initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig'
>   threw an exception."}

With this inner exception :

> {"Unable to open configSource file 'connectionStrings.config'.

How can I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: @Sheridan if it was a duplicate, it would be of this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14873126/connectionstrings-configsource-in-app-config-not-working

Comment: if I reopened this question, then I would not be able to re-close it as a duplicate of your linked question. Either way, it is a duplicate and now you have provided that link, it makes little difference. Any users finding your question can follow either link.