# Visual Studio/TFS: How to provide configuration for unit-tests when running from the console/command-line

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, msbuild, tfs-2015, vstest

VSTest, which is what TFS 2015 uses for unit-tests, wants to ignore application config/settings (app.config) by default. VSTest takes an optional "runsettings" configuration file, but it doesn't accommodate any information about an *app.config* file. Now, from the *runsettings* file, you can tell it to drop into "legacy" mode:

```
<RunSettings>
  <MSTest>
    <ForcedLegacyMode>true</ForcedLegacyMode> 
  </MSTest>
</RunSettings>
```

...and this will allow it to use the *app.config* file in the same directory (these are assemblies/libraries, so the configuration file is just named "app.config" rather than "application.exe.config"). *However*, it will not find *included* files. For example, I have a separate connection-strings file. It's included from the top of the *app.config*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings configSource="connectionStrings.config" />
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
```

I will get an error every time about how it can't find the file:

```
2016-09-21T18:36:12.2439565Z ##[error]Error Message:
2016-09-21T18:36:12.2439565Z ##[error]   Test method Assembly.Project.Class threw exception: 
2016-09-21T18:36:12.2595841Z ##[error]System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Unable to open configSource file 'connectionStrings.config'. (D:\Agents\A3\_work\464b36816\TestResults\Definition_Host 2016-09-21 14_36_09\Out\Assembly.DLL.config line 7)
2016-09-21T18:36:12.2595841Z ##[error]Stack Trace:
```

Since it's only allowed to be relative (otherwise, you'll get another error), I've tried prepending ".\" (which seems like it works in other situations) and well as referencing the next few levels of directories above it, but it will not find the referenced connection-strings file.

Okay. So I wanted to inspect the execution logic in order to figure out what the working directory was. The TFS 2015 task that is initiating the tests is called VSTest.ps1. It *refers* to a cmdlet called "Invoke-PSTest" in order to call "vstest.console.exe" to actually run the tests. This exists absolutely nowhere on the disk as it's own file or in any psd1/psm1 files, so it must be provided by a binary assembly.

However, I'm also apparently avoiding providing a data-source/connection-string to the unit-tests the way that I am supposed to. After all, I'm having to use "legacy" mode in order to get VSTest to use my configuration file.

So, what is the proper way to provide application-configuration (such as a connection-string) to unit-tests? After-all, sometimes you actually need an external resource in order to properly test.

Comment: Could you include an actual error log from the build process?

Comment: Before you run a test, the test and the application have to be copied to a location where they can run, together with other assemblies that they reference. Since the connection-strings file can't be found and  included from the top of the app.config file. Did you deploy the app.config  file ?

Comment: @DanielMann Added the error message.

Comment: @Patrick-MSFT I just added the error-message. You can see that it doesn't have any trouble reading the config file. Everything is in the same directory, though I had tried putting the connection-string config in the root output folder (as mentioned).

Comment: Seems your issue related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14873126/connectionstrings-configsource-in-app-config-not-working  Did you try to copy the file to the Corresponding position in the build agent?